# linux quota how set grace time

Tags: linux, quota

I need create a script to set quota to my virtual users. Quota system works perfectly on my test-server but I can't set "grace time":

```
quotatool -u test001 -bq 100M -l '150 Mb' /home
```

it's easy modify grace time using

edquota -t

but for simplify I prefer use quotatool, from quotatool man page I see:

```
-t TIME Set the system-wide grace period to TIME.  TIME consists of an optional 
'-' or '+' character, a number, and optionally one of  the  following  modifiers:  
"seconds",  "minutes",  "hours",  "days",  "weeks",  or  "months".  Unique 
abbreviations (e.g. "s", "mo") are also accepted. The default is "seconds".  
The argument should be preceded by -u|-g and -b|-i
```

without -t option, grace is 6days, I need put 10days by default

Comment: So just use the `-t` option with quotatool; what is the problem?

Comment: -t 10 days? Does not run: quotatool: must specify either block or inode

Comment: `-t "10 days" `

Comment: same error: quotatool: must specify either block or inode

Answer (score 1):

Grace periods are set on a "global per quotatype and filesystem" basis only.
Each quotatype (usrquota / grpquota) on each filesystem has two grace periods
- one for block limits and one for inode limits.
It is not possible to set different grace periods for users on the same filesystem.